# How to resolve Spotify on Firefox Developer Edition crashing with WidevineCdm plugin?

Tags: spotify, widevine, firefox-developer-edition

Not directly a programming question but certainly one on developer productivity.

Like many developers I'm running the latest version of Firefox DeveloperEdition, to take advantage of all its various toolset, whilst trying to listen to Spotify to drown out the open plan office.

Whilst not the first time this has happened; Spotify crashes repeatedly with the WidevineCdm plugin being blamed as the culprit... this usually happens without any playback, but sometimes after a couple of seconds.

Usually "Help" page hints of fiddling with plugin settings as per usual aren't all that helpful.

I know that it'll likely resolve itself in a few days, but as a curious developer, I would like to know why it persistently breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my fix to use Google chrome instead of Firefox :-(

Answer (score 0):

This error just cropped up on Windows 7 ultra running Firefox to watch Netflix. (August 2019). Chrome worked OK as well as windows 10.  For me i seemed to have found a solution (hopefully) After lots of digging and trying solution I have Netflix working OK by tuning Exploit Protection off in malware-bytes Premium .